# how to provide a custom name for widget in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a widget

```
Comments = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
```

now i want to put above widget in a loop such that it has to make

```
Comments_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True) 
Comments_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)
Comments_3 = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required=True)  
....
....
....
```

as of now i hard coded form fields in django templates as below
simply i want below form in django forms

```
{% for question in questions %}
            <div class="well">    
                    <h3>{{ question|striptags }} </h3>
                    {% if question.enumComment == "1" %}
                        <br>


                                <textarea name="fill_apraisal_comment{{ question.intQuesID }}" rows="3" cols="40" class="form-control">
                                     {{fill_comments|keyvalue:question.intQuesID}}
                                </textarea> 


                   {% endif %}


            </div>
            {% empty %}
                <li>No Questions.</li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Those are 'fields' to be exact :) You want that for validation or rendering a form? Becouse in template you can iterate through form fields.

Comment: i want my own custom name for the field.the fields has to be form depending on count i give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
from django.utils import six
from django.forms.forms import get_declared_fields
from django.forms.widgets import media_property

class IteratedFieldsMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        attrs['base_fields'] = get_declared_fields(bases, attrs)

        i = 0
        while i < 5:
            attrs['base_fields']['Comments_%s' % i] = forms.CharField()
            i = i + 1

        new_class = super(IteratedFieldsMetaclass,
                     cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if 'media' not in attrs:
            new_class.media = media_property(new_class)
        return new_class

class OrderForm(six.with_metaclass(IteratedFieldsMetaclass, forms.BaseForm)):
    pass
```

Have no idea what you need this for but it's possible :)

**EDIT** (about comment):

```
from models import Question

class QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        attrs['base_fields'] = get_declared_fields(bases, attrs)

        for question in Question.objects.all():
            attrs['base_fields']['textbox_question%s' % question.id] = forms.CharField(label = question.question_text)

        new_class = super(QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass,
                     cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        if 'media' not in attrs:
            new_class.media = media_property(new_class)
        return new_class
```

Like that?

Comment: actually i have 5 questions in database with question id.now i want to display text box for each question.so that each text box should form with a name 'textbox_questionid'

Comment: how to use QuestionIteratedFieldsMetaclass  in views and templates?

Comment: iam able to form the textboxes but validations are not working for above code.

Comment: @user2627385 I can't guess how are you trying to use it. Maybe ask another question? Or edit this one?